# Can't log onto Minecraft.net

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just made a Mojang account and it is not letting me sign into Minecraft.net with it. I used my E-mail for my username and everything.

I can sign into Mojang.com no problem what so ever but Minecraft.net says Unknown username or password.

I am completely lost and have no clue what to do.

Comment: @3ventic Good point.  I don't think the one you linked came up on the search.

Comment: Have you purchased Minecraft for your Mojang account yet? If you haven't yet, that's why you can't log into the Minecraft website.